# Getting the solution to a differential equation (epidemiology)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I found this equation in one of some slides that I am reading.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\beta xy$$

with solution:

$$x=\frac{n(n+1)}{n+e^{\beta(n+1)t}}\qquad\qquad y=\frac{n+1}{1+ne^{-\beta(n+1)t}}$$

How are these solutions derived?

`x` and `y` are defined in this context(there is no other equation except for this):
[image]

Comment: I think that problem is underdetermined. One equation and two variables.

Comment: Look around for another equation. Chances are it starts with ${dy\over dt}=\dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing equation in the OP is the equation on $y$ below. If uninfected people $x$ in contact at a rate $\beta>0$ with infected people $y$ become infected and stay infected, then
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
&\frac{dx}{dt} = -\beta x y \, ,\\ \\
&\frac{dy}{dt} = \beta x y \, .
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt} = {-1} \, ,
$$
i.e. $x = x_0 + y_0 - y = n+1-y$. One has to solve
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = \beta \left(n+1 - y\right) y \, ,
$$
which is a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation), with solution
$$
y(t) = \frac{\left(n+1\right) y_0 \,  e^{(n+1)\beta t}}{y_0 \left(e^{(n+1)\beta t} - 1\right) + n+1} = \frac{n+1}{1 + n e^{-\beta(n+1) t}} \, .
$$
Finally, the desired result is obtained.

---

*Note*: This is a particular case of the SIR model of epidemiology (see e.g. the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology)).